# Acts 3:21 Does this scripture prohibit Jesus' return until the " times of restitution of all things " as quoted by Peter in this verse?

Tags: jesus, prophecy, eschatology, second-coming

Acts 3:21 K.J.

> " Whom the heaven must receive until the times of restitution of all
> things, ..... ".

I have heard and read much about Jesus' return being imminent  (likely to happen soon) and according to the definition of imminent that may be true. Unfortunately some add to that and say all scripture has already been fulfilled and nothing else need be fulfilled for Jesus to return.

**Does this verse not say that Jesus is received in Heaven until an appointed time we do not know?**

Answer (score 2):

Acts 3:21 is one of many scriptures that give us "clues" about when Jesus will return, and they all have to be put together to get a clear picture.

You ask about one specific verse, however. Examination of it and surrounding verses show Peter referring quite often to what the prophets of old said about this, going right back to the beginning - "since the world began". The need would therefore be to collate all that the prophets said about Christ returning in glory at the end of the last days. And that would turn this into a topic.

Yes, the words 'receive' and 'until' are significant, because they show that God did receive the resurrected Christ into heaven, and that he would remain there for a time known to God. There is nothing random, or arbitrary about Christ's return! It is not contingent upon unknown factors. God's time-keeping is exquisitely accurate, down to the nth degree. We still await the awesome event of Christ's return to start the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. Those who love their Lord, and who long for his appearing (Titus 2:13) stay alert, because we have not been given to know the exact time. It will be sudden, unexpected, and close the Day of Salvation we are currently in. It will then be too late for anyone to repent and so to be saved.

The book of the Revelation shows that certain things must happen immediately before Christ returns, but symbolic language is used. The seven ***last*** plagues are described. Other plagues have preceded that. The horsemen of the apocalypse have been galloping all over earth since Christ's return to heaven and continue, to this day. But certain things are clearly shown in Revelation to be particular to just before the final show-down, e.g. demonic expressions gathering the nations to the battle of Armageddon (16:14). Also, the final great deception of the nations (20:8). But who wants to be complacent, like the foolish virgins who did not have enough oil for their lamps, and who slept, being caught unprepared? The Revelation was written to keep Christians in every generation alert and expecting Christ's imminent return. It could happen at any time.

Only at Christ's return will there then be "the restitution of all things". 'Restitution' means 'restoring'. His return triggers the start of the spectacular transformation that will result in a new heaven and a new earth in which righteousness shall dwell (2 Peter 3:13). This means that **the answer to the question is that the start of the Day of Resurrection and Judgment at Christ's sudden return leads into "the restitution of all things".**

Answer (score 1):

The RSV translates "until the time for establishing all that God spoke".

Either way, I read the connection between the two events the other way round. That is, the return of Jesus determines when the restitution or establishment takes place, because the latter is the effect of his return.

Comment: Actually we see the same way around. No doubt Jesus' return powers the regeneration, refreshing, or restitution.  My focus was on "heaven must receive until ". It reads to me given the full context that until ALL prophecy must first be fulfilled before Jesus does come. My personal emphasis has been Jesus does not come back until the Gospel is preached or published unto the whole world. Meaning great commission must be fulfilled and then the end will come. Math.24 &  Mk 13.

Comment: I was reading "Prophecy is about the Day of the Lord, when evil is removed from the world, and that is what is fulfilled when Jesus returns".

Comment: @ Stephen Disraeli My KJV version finishes that 3:21 verse with " which God hath spoken by the mouth of all his Holy prophets since the world began." That's where I am getting my idea of all prophecy being fulfilled. As well as Rev. 10 talking about time being no longer at the seventh Trump. Rev. 10:7 " the mystery of God should be finished, as he hath declared to his servants ( notice SERVANTS is plural ) the prophets. Do you think merging all these verses together may be a stretch. I am looking for other opinions on this question.

Comment: I still think that the return of Christ IS the fulfilment of the propecies.

Comment: Let me be specific. Is Jesus required by scripture ( the addressed Acts 3:21) to remain in Heaven until certain prophecies are first fulfilled. The fact that two thousand years have not seen his 2nd coming indicates my understanding of this scripture. Can the word "receive" or the word "until"  be used to further our understanding?

Comment: The implication of my previous answer is "No." He waits until it is time for prophecies to be fulfilled BY his return. The gist of the message is "He waits in heaven until it is time for him tocome back". Having said that, Revelation implies that he comes back to overthow the dominion of the great persecutor, as well as the other evils of the world, so the great persecutor has to come first (see 2 Thessalonians ch2), so perhaps that could be counted as "prophecy fulfilment".

Comment: @ Stephen Disraeli. Thank you for your time and response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150797/discussion-between-rhpclass79-and-stephen-disraeli).

Answer (score 0):

**Must** The meaning of this verse is predicated upon the first part of the sentence: **Heavens must receive**. This verse is merely stating the **position** of Jesus in the present time. It is definitely not setting a **time schedule** limiting or determining when Jesus will return. Such an interpretation would contradict Jesus's previous teaching about there being absolutely **no signs** of His pending return. (Compare Matthew 25, **Watch for you know not the hour.**)

Since we absolutely **do not know**, it is erroneous for any pastor to declare that "We are in the last days." No one can say that the Return is immediate. If "immanent" means "could possibly happen or not in the present," then Jesus' return is an immanent event. No one knows if it is "immediate."

Having said this, the Second Coming (or Return) does encompass several concomitant events: the Regeneration, the end of Death and Dying, the Great Judgment... and thank God, the Resurrection and rewarding of the Righteous, and then the final turning over of the Kingdom to the Father.  (1 Corinthians 15)

**There is nothing that prohibits the Return of Christ.** What prophecies that some consider to yet be fulfilled, can only happen **at** the Second Coming.

Comment: Mathew 24 says otherwise Ray. The whole chapter is predicated on what will be the signs of Jesus' coming and the end of the age.

Comment: @ RHPclass79 - Matthew 24 is an exciting chapter to study.  Please note, however, the declaration of Jesus Himself, that was  mentioned in ch. 24 would take place within **that generation** (Destruction of Judea).  Which it did. There is a definite change in wording when He said, "but of that day and hour..." and a change in topic (Second Coming). It is recommended that you read, **Times, They Are a'Changing** by Raymond Grant,  and **Matthew Twentyfour** by Marcellus Kik. Note that "the age" in Jesus' wording is different from "age" in disciples' question in the Greek.